# Neural network ValueError with Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

I have to train a neural network with keras. For this I use some test data with the following shapes:

```
 print("     Training data: {}".format(x_Train.shape))
 print("     Training data: {}".format(y_Train.shape))
 print("     Test data: {}".format(x_Test.shape))
 print("     Test data: {}".format(y_Test.shape))

 ....

 Training data: (128, 90, 561)
 Training data: (128,)
 Test data: (43, 90, 561)
 Test data: (43,)
```

And this network architecture:

```
class NeuralNetwork:
@staticmethod
def Build(Width, Depth, Classes, Drop = 0.5):
    Model = Sequential()
    Model.add(Conv1D(filters = 32, 
                    kernel_size = 5,
                    input_shape = (Width, Depth)
    ))

    Model.add(Activation("relu"))
    Model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2,
                            strides = 2
    ))

    Model.add(Conv1D(filters = 64, 
                    kernel_size = 3
    ))
    Model.add(Activation("relu"))
    Model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2,
                            strides = 2
    ))

    Model.add(Flatten())
    Model.add(Dense(1024))
    Model.add(Dropout(Drop))
    Model.add(Dense(Classes))
    Model.add(Activation("softmax"))

    return Model
```

But I´ve got this error when I try to train my model:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_3 to have shape (12,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I use this code for training:

```
print("[INFO] Train model...")
self.__Model = NeuralNetwork.Build(90, 561, 12)
plot_model(self.__Model, show_layer_names = True, show_shapes = True)
self.__Model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer  = Adam(lr = self.__Learnrate), metrics = ["accuracy"])
self.__Model.fit(x_Train, 
                    y_Train, 
                    validation_data = (x_Test, y_Test), 
                    batch_size = self.__BatchSize,
                    epochs = self.__Epochs, 
                    verbose = 1
)
```

And I don´t get the source for this error. I test the whole code with tensorflow and it works fine. But I do something wrong with the redesign with keras.

Thank you for an hint or something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing the targets and your loss function. I'm guessing your targets are integer labels for your class `y = [3, 5, 6, ...]` you have up to 12 classes. In this case your loss should be `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` because you want to predict 1 of 12 mutually exclusive classes.

The error says that you are outputting a distribution over 12 classes but giving a single target. Something like `out = [0.2, 0.5, 0.1, ...]` and `y = [2]` this is the shape mismatch between (12,) and (1,). Sparse categorical coverts your target label into a one-hot vector, so it becomes `y = [0,0,1,0,...]`

Comment: Well, thank you. The loss function produce the error. The training is successfull after changing it to crossentropy. 
Finaly I found my misstake. I used the LabelEncoder from sklearn instead of the LabelBinarizer. So I don´t get the one-hot vectors....